# March of the Monarchs vs Negate Tribute Summon

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Player A already has [March of the Monarchs](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/March_of_the_Monarchs) active on their field, which protects their tribute summoned monsters from being targeted or destroyed.

Player A attempts to tribute summon a monster face-up, but player B activates [Solemn Judgement](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Solemn_Judgment).

**Question**: Can player B activate Solemn Judgement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes, Player B can activate Solemn Judgement.

Note the activation timing of Solemn Judgement (emphasis mine):

> When a monster(s) **would be Summoned**,

I.e., the monster's summon has not been completed.

It is therefore not yet a Tribute Summoned monster, and receives no protection from March of the Monarchs.